Why is python mock assert_any_call not matching
Given the doc for assert_any_call

I have a log statement I want to assert against
...
logger.warning('Backup quantity is 0, supplied uuids %s, matched machines: %s', uuids, machines)
...

see the last 3 lines of my unit test (first 2 lines for investigation purpose only)
# deliberate fail so it prints what it expects
logger.warning.assert_not_called()

# prints the params used in the official assert
print('Backup quantity is 0, supplied uuids %s, matched machines: %s', [vm3_uuid], VirtualMachine.objects.none())

# actual official assert
logger.warning.assert_any_call('Backup quantity is 0, supplied uuids %s, matched machines: %s', [vm3_uuid], VirtualMachine.objects.none())

The output for the test assert_not_called was:
AssertionError: Expected 'warning' to not have been called. Called 2 times.
Calls: [call('Backup quantity is 0, supplied uuids %s, matched machines: %s', ['232d7937-975c-457b-8a11-ac473d0e04a0'], <QuerySet []>),
 call('%s %s cannot find proxmox UUID from BIS', 'DEF-456', 'vm4')]

The param print was
Backup quantity is 0, supplied uuids %s, matched machines: %s ['232d7937-975c-457b-8a11-ac473d0e04a0'] <QuerySet []>

The offical assert failed
AssertionError: warning('Backup quantity is 0, supplied uuids %s, matched machines: %s', ['232d7937-975c-457b-8a11-ac473d0e04a0'], <QuerySet []>) call not found

Unless I missed something very obvious, I don't know why the assert_any_call would fail?

VirtualMachine.objects.none() may return an empty QuerySet, but that doesn't mean it's going to compare equal to another empty QuerySet. The value you pass to assert_any_call isn't the same object that was passed to the actual warning call, and isn't equal to that original object either.
For your assertion to pass, the querysets would have to compare equal with ==.

ahhh never thought of they would not equal, so in this case how would I make it to assert it correctly since I can't reproduce the same empty queryset via .none()?

@JamesLin: I don't know if there's a better way, but the first option that comes to mind is manually inspecting the calls list for a call that matches the pattern you're expecting.

I added my solution as an answer since the comment section won't display it well, do you think my solution is okay?

@JamesLin: Looks like it should work fine.

My answer is just the supplement @user2357112's, I thought I'd share how I overcome my problem, I am not sure if this is the canonical way to do it though.
I created a custom EmptyQuerySet class that implements __eq__ to check if the compared object is an object of the QuerySet class and count() returns 0.
class EmptyQuerySet(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, QuerySet) and other.count() == 0:
            return True
        return super(EmptyQuerySet, self).__eq__(other)

And then I use it to be part of the assertion as below and it worked.
logger.warning.assert_any_call('Backup quantity is 0, supplied uuids %s, matched machines: %s', [vm3_uuid], EmptyQuerySet())

